# Appcelerator Titanium - marker on Image

Tags: imageview, cross-platform, overlay, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have a floor plan of the building in which need to place marker on different location of the rooms and area. I have achieved this in Android native but needs to do for the cross platform in titanium. 
The approach I used was - get the x,y coordinates for each room and overlay a flag icon or something. I'm not sure how this would work with titanium.

Any other approaches will also be good.

The main idea of the app is highlight the room with marker when user search for the particular room.

Thanks

Comment: Have you achieved the solution?

Comment: Yes. will post an answer soon..!